# remove quotation marks from string at beginning and end only if both are present

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I want to clean up a string that contains escaped quotation marks. I want to remove the escaped quotation marks the end and beginning of a string but keep intact all qoutation marks within the string. What I came up with is the following.

```
library(stringr)
s1 <- "\"He said:\"Hello\" - some word\""
str_replace_all(s1, "(^\\\")|(\\\"$)", "")

> [1] "He said:\"Hello\" - some word"
```

What I am struggling with now is that I only want to remove the quotation marks if and only if there is one at the beginning AND at the end. Otherwise not.The following expression falsely removes the leading one.

```
s2 <- "\"Hello!\" he said"
str_replace_all(s2, "(^\\\")|(\\\"$)", "")

> [1] "Hello!\" he said"
```

Here my regex should indicate that I only want to remove them in case the whole string is wrapped in escaped quotation marks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following regex seems to work on your examples:

```
s <- c("\"He said:\"Hello\" - some word\"", "\"Hello!\" he said")
```

The regex uses back-references (`\\1`) to return only the string inside the leading quote `^\"` and the trailing quote `\"$`:

```
r <- gsub("^\"(.*)\"$", "\\1", s)
```

This results in:

```
cat(r, sep="\n")
He said:"Hello" - some word
"Hello!" he said
```